# Query is giving me error message : The multi-part identifier "llpeople_tbl.Person_ecounsel" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
>   The multi-part identifier "llpeople_tbl.Person_ecounsel" could not be bound.

```
 insert into [dbo].[Counsellor]
(
 [TenantId], [EmployeeId])

select 1, [Id]
 from [Employee] where llpeople_tbl.Person_ecounsel = 1
```

Comment: If the source for an `insert` is a `select`, the `select` statement should be executable on its own. In this case, you refer to `llpeople_tbl` which is not present in the `from` clause

Comment: Is the column `Person_ecounsel` in the `Employee` table or another table entirely?

Answer (score 0):

Cause :

> This error usually occurs when an alias is used when referencing a column in a SELECT statement and the alias used is not defined anywhere in the FROM clause of the SELECT statement.

if the column `Person_ecounsel` is from table `Employee`, you either give the alias `llpeople_tbl` to Employee table or remove it as shown below.

```
insert into [dbo].[Counsellor]
(
 [TenantId], [EmployeeId])

select 1, [Id]
 from [Employee] where Person_ecounsel = 1
```

if the column `Person_ecounsel` is from different table, you should join that table (`llpeople_tbl`) accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a `JOIN` or a connection between the tables.  I can speculate that you want something like this:

```
insert into [dbo].[Counsellor ([TenantId], [EmployeeId])
    select 1, e.[Id]
    from [Employee] e
    where exists (select 1
                  from llpeople_tbl t
                  where t.person_id = e.person_id and 
                        t.Person_ecounsel = 1
                 );
```

I am speculating that a column such as `person_id` is used to connect the tables.